# Can't install octocatalog-diff

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to run:

```
gem install octocatalog-diff -v 1.5.2
```

(Since later versions require ruby 2.2.0).
This is the error I'm getting:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing octocatalog-diff:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
.
.
.
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:167 (MESSAGE):
  Unable to autodetect a usable HTTPS backend.Please pass the backend name
  explicitly (-DUSE_HTTPS=backend)
```

Although I have openssl installed and in my user's path.
Tried installing ruby-devel, cmake,gcc

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone will stumble across this, the solution here was to install openssl-devel package:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

That solved it for me.